# How to click once and nav to request page?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

The question is,
why i need to click twice on the 'Login' button to show the requested page?

```
onSubmit() {
let email = this.logiinForm.value.email
let password = this.logiinForm.value.password


this.storagService.getToken(email, password, this.userType).subscribe(
  tokenObj => {
    this.token = tokenObj.token.toString()
    this.tokenLength = this.token.length
  })

if (this.userType === 'admin'&& this.tokenLength === 15) {
  this.router.navigate(['admin-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })
} else if (this.userType === 'company' && this.tokenLength === 10) {
  this.router.navigate(['company-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })
} else if (this.userType === 'customer' && this.tokenLength === 5) {
  this.router.navigate(['customer-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })

  /* Add 'else' for error. */
}
```

**If i delete the check "this.tokenLength === 15" all work just fine!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
onSubmit() {
let email = this.logiinForm.value.email
let password = this.logiinForm.value.password


this.storagService.getToken(email, password, this.userType).subscribe(
  tokenObj => {
    this.token = tokenObj.token.toString()
    this.tokenLength = this.token.length

    if (this.userType === 'admin'&& this.tokenLength === 15) {
      this.router.navigate(['admin-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })
    } else if (this.userType === 'company' && this.tokenLength === 10) {
      this.router.navigate(['company-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })
    } else if (this.userType === 'customer' && this.tokenLength === 5) {
      this.router.navigate(['customer-main'], { relativeTo: this.route })

      /* Add 'else' for error. */
  })
}
```